# Capitalisation of First Letter of Each Word in a List; Bar All-Caps Words

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, capitalization

I need to write a program that can capitalise each word in a sentence (which is stored as a list of words), **without** affecting the capitalisation of other parts of the sentence.

Let's say, for example, the sentence is 'hello, i am ROB ALSOD'. In a list, this would be:

```
['hello,','i','am','ROB','ALSOD']
```

I understand that I could loop through and use the `str.title()` method to title them, but this would result in:

```
['Hello,','I','Am','Rob','Alsod']
```

Notice the difference? The effect I am going for is:

```
['Hello,','I','Am','ROB','ALSOD']
```

In other words, I want to keep other capitalised letters the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a one-liner, using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and string [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1014938):

```
>>> words = ['hello,','i','am','ROB','ALSOD']
>>> [word[:1].upper() + word[1:] for word in words]
['Hello,', 'I', 'Am', 'ROB', 'ALSOD']
```

It uppercases `word[:1]` (everything up to and including the first character) rather than `word[0]` (the first character itself) in order to avoid an error if your list contains the empty string `''`.

Answer (score 0):

While [Zero Piraeus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18094409/2392038) is correct, I'd be down for a more [functional syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools) that avoids loops.

```
>>> words = ['hello,','i','am','ROB','ALSOD']
>>> def up(word): return word[:1].upper() + word[1:]
>>> map(up, words)
['Hello,', 'I', 'Am', 'ROB', 'ALSOD']
```

Comment: In Python 3.x, `map()` [returns an iterator](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.0#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) rather than a list, so your last line would need to be `list(map(up, words))`. By the way, `map()` doesn't avoid loops but merely hides them (just like list comprehensions) - usually, as in this case, with a significant performance penalty over listcomps.